# How to apply build trigger for bitbucket in jenkins from groovy sccript?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to trigger the bitbucket push for some jobs using groovy scripts.

```
for(item in Hudson.instance.items)
{
    item.addTrigger(com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.BitBucketTrigger$DescriptorImpl)

  }
```

But it is not enabling the trigger. What would be the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def trigger = new com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.BitBucketTrigger()
for(item in Hudson.instance.items)
{
    item.addTrigger(trigger)

}
```